# based on status response from the server want to display message in android

Tags: android, json

Hi in the below code i have login activity.In that if the username and password am sending request through json .If the username and passwords are correct then server sending json response as json format

In json response contains key status and usertype.If status is success and user type.based on user type redirecting to particular page.

But now my problem is if the email and passwords are incorrect from server sending response as json format.In that contains on one key named as status.

if the status is invalid the want to show the message as toast format.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        API service = retrofit.create(API.class);

        try{
            JSONObject parmobject=new JSONObject ();
            parmobject.put("emailMobile",emailMobile);
            parmobject.put("password",password);
            Call<Login> userCall = service.getUser(parmobject.toString ());
            userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Login> () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {


                    if (response != null && response.code ()==200) {
                        status = response.body ( ).getStatus ( ).toString ( );
                        usertype = response.body ( ).getUsertype ( ).toString ( );


                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success") && usertype.equalsIgnoreCase ("admin")) {
                            // dialog.dismiss();
                            makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                            Intent mainIntent;
                            mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, NavigationViewActivity.class);
                            startActivity (mainIntent);
                            finish ( );
                        }
                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success") && usertype.equalsIgnoreCase ("operator")) {
                            // dialog.dismiss();
                            makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                            Intent mainIntent;
                            mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, OperatorHome.class);
                            startActivity (mainIntent);
                            finish ( );
                        }

                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success") && usertype.equalsIgnoreCase ("employee")) {
                            // dialog.dismiss();
                            makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                            Intent mainIntent;
                            mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, EmployeeHome.class);
                            startActivity (mainIntent);
                            finish ( );
                        }


                    }

                    if (response != null && response.isSuccessful ()&& response.code ()==401)  {

                            status = response.body().getStatus ().toString ( );

                            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("Invalid login credentials")) {

                                // dialog.dismiss();
                                makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Invalid login credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
//                            Intent mainIntent;
//                            mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
//                            startActivity (mainIntent);
//                            finish ( );
//                        }
                            }

                    }
                }
//                      else {
//                          if(status.equalsIgnoreCase ("Invalid login credentials"))
//                        makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid EmailId and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        progressDialog.dismiss ();
//                    }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                    progressDialog.dismiss ();
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retrofit;
```

Comment: Handle in same way as you are handling "success" or other status

Answer (score 0):

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
API service = retrofit.create(API.class);

    try{
    JSONObject parmobject=new JSONObject ();
    parmobject.put("emailMobile",emailMobile);
    parmobject.put("password",password);
    Call<Login> userCall = service.getUser(parmobject.toString ());
    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Login> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {


            if (response != null && response.code ()==200) {
                status = response.body ( ).getStatus ( ).toString ( );
                usertype = response.body ( ).getUsertype ( ).toString ( );


                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success") && usertype.equalsIgnoreCase ("admin")) {
                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, NavigationViewActivity.class);
                    startActivity (mainIntent);
                    finish ( );
                }
                else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success") && usertype.equalsIgnoreCase ("operator")) {
                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, OperatorHome.class);
                    startActivity (mainIntent);
                    finish ( );
                }

                else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("success") && usertype.equalsIgnoreCase ("employee")) {
                    // dialog.dismiss();
                    makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, EmployeeHome.class);
                    startActivity (mainIntent);
                    finish ( );
                }
                else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase ("invalid"))
                {
                    makeText (LoginActivity.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );

                }
                else
                {
                    makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Invalid login credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );

                }
            }
            else
            {
                makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Invalid login credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            progressDialog.dismiss ();
        }
    });
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return retrofit;
```

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://xxxxxx/login} from server.everytime it is executing else block

Comment: else
            {
                makeText (LoginActivity.this, "Invalid login credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
            }

Comment: when you entered valid credential then above code is working or not  ?

Comment: for valid credential my code also working fine.Invalid credentials only am facing issue

Comment: but status param is not from Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=xxxxxx/login} from serve that's why else part is calling.. just check response